# SwiftUI app crashing before firebase fetched data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to fetch some data from firebase and display it as text, however it instantly fails with `fatal error 'index out of range'`, however when I try without putting anything in the text the firebase data does load and is printed correctly, it just seems that the view is loading quicker than the firebase data is being fetched. Are there any errors in my code that I should be aware of or does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can fix this problem. Thanks

FirebasetestApp

```
@main
struct FirebasetestApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var dataManager = DataManager()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView().environmentObject(dataManager)
        }
    }
}
```

MainView

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: DataManager
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Text(dataManager.prompts[0].text)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)

            }.padding()
            
            Divider()
            
        }
    }
}
```

DataManager

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftUI

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var prompts: [Prompts] = []
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() {
        fetchPrompts()
    }
    
    func fetchPrompts() {
        
        db.collection("prompts").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
              guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("no documents")
                return
              }

              self.prompts = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Prompts in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                  
                let text = data["promptText"] as? String ?? ""
                let id = data["id"] as? Int ?? 0

                return Prompts(id: id, text: text)
              }
        }
                    
    }
}
```

And this is how prompts is defined

```
import SwiftUI

struct Prompts: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
}
```

Comment: You can’t access an array using index in your view before the array contains values, `dataManager.prompts[0]`. Use a ForEach instead.

Comment: The view will, and should, always load before data is applied to it. Therefore, when constructing the view, always build it in the absence of data, which will be its default state. Then when data is applied, this default state changes. So, in the most rudimentary example, `if` there is data then the UI looks like this, `else`, if there isn't data, then it looks like that. In your example, you've only constructed the UI to handle the presence of data, not the absence.

Comment: if you really really need to have a `Text(...)` view, then try using this: 
`if dataManager.prompts.count > 0 { Text(dataManager.prompts[0].text) ..... }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `MainView` to:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: DataManager
    
    @State var promptText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Text(promptText)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .redacted(reason: promptText == "" ? .placeholder : [])

            }.padding()
            
            Divider()
            
        }
        .task {
            if let firstPrompt = $dataManager.prompts.first {
                promptText = firstPrompt.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and add this extra verification in your `fetchPrompts` method:

```swift
...

        db.collection("prompts").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents, !documents.isEmpty else {
                print("no documents")
                return
              }
            
            self.prompts = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Prompts in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                
                let text = data["promptText"] as? String ?? ""
                let id = data["id"] as? Int ?? 0
                
                return Prompts(id: id, text: text)
            }
        }
...
```

You should now be able to preview a loading effect for a few moments and then you will see the value (if any) in the text field.